# batch file - extract all file with matching file extension

Tags: batch-file

I want to get all font files from our NAS with a batch file and copy them to a folder.

I came up with this. It works but it starts the search from the beginning with every new file extension which isn't good (searching takes time its 8 TB).

How can I do it at the same time for all file extensions?

```
@ECHO off
SET font[0]=OTF
SET font[1]=TTF
SET font[2]=FNT
SET font[3]=WOFF
SET font[4]=WOFF2
SET font[5]=AFM
SET font[6]=AMFM
SET font[7]=BDF
SET font[8]=CHA
SET font[9]=CHR
SET font[10]=COMPOSITEFONT
SET font[11]=DFONT
SET font[12]=EOT
SET font[13]=ETX
SET font[14]=EUF
SET font[15]=F3F
SET font[16]=FFIL
SET font[17]=FONFOT
SET font[18]=GDR
SET font[19]=GF
SET font[20]=GXF
SET font[21]=LWFN
SET font[22]=MCF
SET font[23]=MF
SET font[24]=MXF
SET font[25]=NFTR
SET font[26]=ODTTF
SET font[27]=PCF
SET font[28]=PFA
SET font[29]=PFB
SET font[30]=PFM
SET font[31]=PFR
SET font[32]=PKJ
SET font[33]=PM
SET font[34]=SFD
SET font[35]=SFP
SET font[36]=SUIT
SET font[37]=T65
SET font[38]=TFM
SET font[39]=TTC
SET font[40]=TTE
SET font[41]=TXF
SET font[42]=VFB
SET font[43]=VLW
SET font[44]=VNF
SET font[45]=ABF
SET font[46]=ACFM
SET font[47]=XFN
SET font[48]=XFT
SET font[49]=YTF

ECHO Suche Fonts

PUSHD "\\192.168.0.222\DataCenter2"

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('SET font[') do FOR /R %%F in ("*.%%s") DO ECHO Kopiere nach "C:\fonts\ausgabe\%%~nxF" & COPY "%%F" "C:\fonts\ausgabe\%%~nxF" /Z /Y

ECHO Suche beendet

TIMEOUT 60
```

Comment: You can use multiple file masks with the `FOR` and `DIR` commands.  So you just need to build a long file mask string. `for /R %%G IN (*.doc *.txt) do @echo %%G`  or `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir *.txt *.doc /b /s') do echo %%G`

Comment: Thanks that works and it's a really neat solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%s in ('
 dir /s/b/a-d *.*^|findstr /L /E /I /g:"fontexts.txt"') do ECHO Kopiere nach "C:\fonts\ausgabe\%%~nxF" & COPY "%%F" "C:\fonts\ausgabe\%%~nxF" /Z /Y
```

where "fontexts.txt" contains

> .otf
>   .ttf
>   .fnt
>   ...etc

Your problem is that you are executing the entire scan 49 times.

This approach performs a complete directory-scan without directorynames (ie. filepaths only) then uses `findstr` to filter the result, checking `/L` literal-matches `/E` that end `/i` regardless of case `/g:"anything in this file"`

Comment: Would be interesting to do a timed test against 8 Terrabytes using your code and then just building the file mask string to use within the `FOR /R`.